# Laravel 4 - Undefined variable in select list using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm struggling to see why my select list is returning an error.

I have a nested foreach loop, the second loop which should display records by building_id.  However it is this very id which it returns an undefined variable for ($building->id)

Is it the construction of the query which is at fault?

```
<select>
     @foreach (Building::orderBy('title')->get() as $building)
          <optgroup label="{{ $building->title }}"></optgroup>
           @foreach (Floor::whereIn('id', function($query){
                 $query->select('floor_id')
                   ->from('rooms')
                   ->where('building_id', $building->id)->distinct();
                   })->get() as $floor)
            <option value="{{ $floor->id }}">{{ $floor->description }}</option>
           @endforeach    
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a closure function which you have passed to `Floor::whereIn`
So this closure function can't recognize external variables like the variable / object ($building) that you wanted to use in it.
so you have to tell PHP to use this $bulding variable in this closure / anonymous function:

```
<select>
     @foreach (Building::orderBy('title')->get() as $building)
          <optgroup label="{{ $building->title }}"></optgroup>
           @foreach (Floor::whereIn('id', function($query) use ($building){
                 $query->select('floor_id')
                   ->from('rooms')
                   ->where('building_id', $building->id)->distinct();
                   })->get() as $floor)
            <option value="{{ $floor->id }}">{{ $floor->description }}</option>
           @endforeach    
     @endforeach
</select>
```

So now the function can reconize this variable :)
Read more about it : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Thank you for your informed answer. That's it working perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
  ....
  @foreach (Floor::whereIn('id', function($query) use ($building){
  ...
```